# Can't clone an existing repository with ssh, and ssh config seems fine

Tags: git, github, permission-denied, git-clone

Here's my situation:
I have two **private** repositories.

- git@github.com:syra37fGIT/Angular.git
- git@github.com:syra37fGIT/temp.git

Currently i added a remote just for one of them by cloning it.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:syra37fGIT/temp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:syra37fGIT/temp.git (push)
```

**ssh is configured correctly i think**, since:

i generated both private (id_rsa) and public (id_rsa.pub) keys

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 Pietro 197121    0 Mar  5 00:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 Pietro 197121    0 Mar 17 09:19 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 Pietro 197121 3389 Mar  5 00:18 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 Pietro 197121  747 Mar  5 00:18 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 Pietro 197121 2790 Mar  5 00:29 known_hosts
```

the public key is correctly setted into my github account Personal settings/SSH and GPG keys

[public key setted on account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmT3E.png)

the private key also seems correctly registered

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 7696

$ ssh-add
Identity added: /c/Users/Pietro/.ssh/id_rsa (syra37fGIT@yandex.com)
```

as proof, i can actually push commits into the added repository whithout problems (no password required since ssh is active)

```
(master)$ echo -e "\ndamn u damn" > README.txt
(master)$ git add .
(master)$ $ git commit -m "damn u commit"
          [master dae7dfd] damn u commit
            1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
(master)$ git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 263 bytes | 263.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To github.com:syra37fGIT/temp.git 
  54bc492..dae7dfd  master -> master
```

and also the authentication test works

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi syra37fGIT! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Given this, **when i try to clone the other repository, the error message below appears**...

```
$ git clone git@github.com:syra37fGIT/Angular.git
Cloning into 'Angular'...
\302\226git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Every tips suggested in 
https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey
is satisfied (i'm on windows machine). Where i'm doing wrong?

Just a tip: there's a chance that one of there two repositories was first cloned with https and then transformed into ssh ([FROM HTTPS TO SSH](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh))... I can't tell if this can be a clue or not to the problem.

**UPDATE:** as the comment below suggests,  the problem was that while visually the repo string was correct, the actual one sent was wrong. The issue is solved.

Comment: But it tells you what went wrong: `\302\226git@github.com: ...` There is garbage before `git@`.

Comment: garbage? The command i used is the right one
"git clone git@github.com:syra37fGIT/Angular.git"
it's not that i inserted the wrong thing... i'll try search with that garbage then. Still i made another private repo and had the same problem. I managed to clone it with https and then switch to ssh.

Comment: That is what you *see* in the terminal, but not what the terminal sent to the ssh command. The ssh command reports that it attempted to connect with user `\302\226git`, not user `git`. Wherever it got these extra bytes from, I cannot tell. Perhaps a fat-fingered copy-and-paste? Or you typed a non-ASCII character and then Backspace deleted just the last UTF-8 octet?

Comment: After trying again with another new repo, it worked fine. I guess it's exactly like you said, though i don't know how on earth that "garbage" ended up there since i copy-pasted with the dedicated button (the one in the github repo page) the SSHrepo string. And it happened again the first time i retried. I definetly didn't pay attention to those garbage chars (i thought they were git stuff related to git using hash everywhere). So be it, now it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [seen here](https://superuser.com/a/1316741/141), if the command is the result of a copy-paste, it can embark invisible special characters which will make the command fails.

A basic double-check to do in this instance is to type again the command manually, and see if the issue persists.

As [commented here](https://superuser.com/questions/1315630/not-able-to-export-key-in-cygwin-bash-bash-302-226-302-226gpg-command-no#comment1958573_1315630), '`\302\226`' is `0xC2 0x96` aka [`U+0096` in UTF-8 encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm).
See [more here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495650/7490):

> The original source for this was likely a byte 0x96 in some single-byte 8-bit encoding that has been transcoded incorrectly somewhere along the way. Probably this was originally a [Windows CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) en dash "`–`", which has byte value 96 in that encoding, which has been translated to UTF-8 as though it was [latin-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), which is not uncommon.